# How to move time 2 hours forward and loop the code everytime the set time is met?

Tags: python, loops, datetime, time, timer

I want to loop my code when it reaches the end and move the set time forward by 2 hours whenever the code loops to beginning. How could I do it with existing code?
Editing the code as per 1st suggestion and adding loop:

```
import pynput
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from threading import Timer
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import schedule
import time

count = 0
while count <3:
    x=datetime.today()
    y=x.replace(day=x.day+0, hour=16, minute=37, second=00, microsecond=0)
    delta_t=y-x
 
    secs=delta_t.seconds+0.02

    keyboard = Controller()


    def bump():
        keyboard.type("!d bump")
        time.sleep (.1)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        time.sleep (.1)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    

    

    t = Timer(secs, bump)
    t.start()
    plus2 = x + timedelta(hours=2)
    count +=1
    
        
    
    t = Timer(secs, bump)
    t.start()
```

Comment: My suggestion wasn't meant to be used arbitrarily; you need to know what your code is doing. First, you added the `plus2` variable but you're not using it anywhere. Second, you're using a `Timer` object, which will do the countdown for you, so you just need to specify the right amount of time to wait as the first parameter (and you don't need to invoke twice).

Comment: Thank you, this explains it. I got it now.